# Set variable inside keypress() event and get one inside keyup() event

Tags: jquery, keypress, keyup

I have some code where i combine **.keypress()** and **.keyup()** events:

```
    $(this).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
        var layout = 'undefined';
        if (e.type == "keypress") {
            // set layout
            layout = 'en';    
        } else {
            // use layout
            alert(layout);
        }
    });
```

As we know the order is **.keydown() -> .keypress() -> .keyup()**. But on **.keyup()** event variable `layout` is always `undefined`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: in this wahta is $(this) is it input?

Comment: when keypress occurs it initialize as 'undefined' and then goes in if part and sets as 'en' but at the keyup event it again initilized as 'undefined' and this time it goes to else part and won't set as 'en'. so solution is just define your variable layour globel so it won't initialize at both keypress & keyup event.

Comment: OK Sohil! It was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `layout` variable outside the event function - you are resetting it to `'undefined'` every event.

```
var layout = 'undefined';
$(this).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "keypress") {
        // set layout
        layout = 'en';    
    } else {
        // use layout
        alert(layout);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

make your `layout` variable global

```
var layout = 'undefined';
$(this).on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.type == "keypress") {
        // set layout
        layout = 'en';    
    } else {
        // use layout
        alert(layout);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 var layout = 'undefined';
 $('input').on('keypress keyup', function (e) {
     if (e.type == "keypress") {
         // set layout
         layout = 'en';
     } else {
         // use layout
         alert(layout);
     }
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yb2Px/)